# Visual Studio 2010 Premium and Windows 7 Mobile dev

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am interested in starting Windows 7 Mobile dev and have searched the net for tutorials.  Each says I should install Visual Studio 2010 Express For Phone to accomplish the task. I have VS 2010 Premium but can't find the templates and the tutorials they speak of in it.

I find it redundant to have two versions of VS installed so I guess my question is can I develop for the Windows 7 Mobile platform directly from VS 2010 Premium?  Am I missing some sort of service pack that will install the templates or do I have to install Express For Phone in parallel with Premium to accomplish this?  Can this even be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web installer of the package should already detect the presence of VS2010 and just install the add ins necessary for WP7 development.

Comment: This is correct although the installer does install the Express version, it just doesn't create the short cuts and file associations if there's another version of VS2010 already installed.

Comment: So let me get this right... I will have two versions of VS installed after the installation process?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this link:

[Installing Windows Phone Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402530%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

and then choose for C# or Visual Basic which package to install.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by changing the language of visual studio. Visual studio needs to have the same language of the windows phone SDK.

Answer (score 0):

For more convenience and ease of developing, i suggest, you may want to switch over to Visual Studio 2012. You can get it from [Here.](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-phone)

As you're wanting to develop for Win 7 Phone.

 VS2012 has very useful templates already installed.And it makes app development very convenient.